# Powershell quotes are not visible on the screen

Tags: powershell, windows-10

In powershell under W10, when I type cd "xxxx", the "xxxx" are not visible on the screen (the cursor moves but the characters print in the same color as the background). When I type the first double quote then the `>` at the beginning of the line turns red and when I type final quotes it turns back to white and the rest of the line is visible.

For example if I type:

```
>cd "Desktop" Hello
```

I get:

```
>cd           Hello
```

My powershell used to work well until yesterday... Do you know how to correct this bug?

Comment: What changed yesterday? Any Windows updates? Any edits to your PS profile? Does it happen in ISE as well as the PS console?

Comment: Please run `(gcm -Name prompt).definition` and include it in your question to make your question Minimum, Complete and Verifiable.

Comment: Also try `Get-Module PSReadline` and have a look at the version; that could help us. I suspect `Remove-Module PSReadline` will also offer you a temporary respite.

Comment: This just sounds like your colorblind my dude. You can change all the font colors in the settings

Comment: > (gcm -Name prompt).definition

"PS $($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation)$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) ";
# .Link
# http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=225750
# .ExternalHelp System.Management.Automation.dll-help.xml

Comment: > Get-Module PSReadline

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Script     1.2        PSReadline                          {Get-PSReadlineKeyHandler, Get-PSReadlineOption, Remove-PS...

Comment: I already checked the color settings, I can't see anything wrong there and I haven't touched it lately. In fact I didn't touch anything as far as I remember, it just suddenly happened. I doesn't occur in ISE, the quotes and the text inside the quotes just appear in red color with a red waving underline

Comment: @VideoPac The default settings for the powershell prompt does make it hard to see text in quotes in general. It normally appears in a light blue, while the background is dark blue. This could be what your experiencing, but is normal. Make it more visible by changing "Screen Text" to a more contrasting color than the default cyan

Comment: No windows update recently, no change to my PS profile. I doesn't occur in ISE, the quotes and the text inside the quotes just appears in red color with a red waving underline

Comment: Changing the color settings doesn't make anything... The strange thing is the > becoming red when I type a " and then returning to white when I close it as if it was a wrong character...

Comment: Maybe a screenshot of what is displayed on your screen would actually help here? I think you can put at least one hyperlink in your question.

Comment: I don't have any real answer to my question but for some reason after exiting and reopening Powershell several times the problem just finally solved by itself. I can see my quotes again... Probably just some weird bug

Comment: have you tried `remove-module psreadline` and tried it again and see if it works?

Comment: i had the same issue. removing `psreadline` was the fix.

Comment: FWIW, `remove-module psreadline` works only on the current session/terminal window for me, i.e., it doesn't stick and has to be repeated each time I open a PS window :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Edit

I found out why this happens, it has to do with the palette in the Colors tab.

If you edit the values in the palette when choosing your text/background colors (which I did by accident), you can change the color of quoted strings.

The 4th value is the one related to quoted strings:

[image]

Hope it helps!

## Old solution

The command below suggested by [TravisEz13](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2658816/travisez13) works.

```
remove-module psreadline
```

But it also removes the nice syntax highlight. It's local solution, you'll have to do it every time you open a new PowerShell session.

Comment: Hey, I couldn't find any definitive solution. The problem solved by itself once but reappeared a few days later... I eventually realized that the problem comes from the fact that the quote is written in the same color as the background so if you change the background color you should be able to see what you are writting...

Comment: I discovered some things, it has to do with the color palette in the menu. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: To clarify, the colour palette affects the colour of syntax highlighted text elements generally. The four radio button options allow you to choose from within the colour palette the output text and background colours for the main window and popups.